# React Enzyme setState does not work when attepting to test with mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test this code block, in my React App with Jest and Enzyme:

```
  openDeleteUserModal = ({ row }: { row: IUser | null }): any => (
    event: React.SyntheticEvent
  ): void => {
    if (event) event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ userToDelete: row, isDeleteUserModalOpen: true });
  };
```

This is the test:

```
    describe('OpenDeleteUserModal', () => {
      let wrapper: ReactWrapper;
      let instance: any;
      beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = mount(
          <MemoryRouter>
            <Route render={props => <UsersOverviewScreen {...props} {...defaultProps} />} />
          </MemoryRouter>
        );
        instance = getComponentInstance(wrapper);
        instance.openDeleteUserModal({ user: mockUser });
        wrapper.update();
      });
      it('should SET the isDeleteUserModalOpen to true', () => {
        expect(instance.state.isDeleteUserModalOpen).toBeTruthy();
      });
      it('should SET the userToDelete to mockUser', () => {
        expect(instance.state.userToDelete).toEqual(mockUser);
      });
    });
```

The test and file are `.tsx`, which means all the boilerplate regarding React Router is needed. I get back false, and undefined instead of true.

I tried to simulate the click but with no luck. See below:

```
      it('should SET the isDeleteUserModalOpen to true', () => {
        const deleteUserButton = wrapper.find('renderUsers').find('button');
        deleteUserButton.simulate('click');
        jest.spyOn(instance, 'openDeleteUserModal');
        instance.openDeleteUserModal();
        expect(instance.openDeleteUserModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(instance.state.isDeleteUserModalOpen).toBeTruthy();
      });
```

Can someone help me understand why is this failing.

Comment: Can you share the error log?

Comment: `{Expected: true, Received: false}, for the first test. {Expected: MockUser, Recieved: undefined}`. That is the error I am getting with or without the solution I tried. It seems the click event is not happening.

Comment: I was thinking of removing the `preventDefault` from the actual funtion. That would solve the problem, but then the state is a mess. Need to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going through the enzyme github [sample enzyme tests](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/packages/enzyme-test-suite/test/ReactWrapper-spec.jsx). Try this out

```
describe('OpenDeleteUserModal', () => {
  let wrapper: ReactWrapper;
  let instance: any;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Route render={props => <UsersOverviewScreen {...props} {...defaultProps} />} />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
    instance = getComponentInstance(wrapper);
    instance.openDeleteUserModal({ user: mockUser });
    // wrapper.update(); --don't think this is required but do check!
  });
  it('should SET the isDeleteUserModalOpen to true', () => {
    //expect(instance.state.isDeleteUserModalOpen).toBeTruthy();
    expect(wrapper.state('isDeleteUserModalOpen')).toBeTruthy();
  });
  it('should SET the userToDelete to mockUser', () => {
    //expect(instance.state.userToDelete).toEqual(mockUser);
    expect(wrapper.state('userToDelete')).toEqual(mockUser);
  });
});
```

> This is most probably because setState() is an async operation. When your
>   test line runs the relevant state might not have been initialized.
>   Enzyme seems to have provided an API for this.

For the second part this is a small caveat in Enzyme when testing arrow functions. Checkout my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55416708/enzyme-onclick-spy-tohavebeencalled-test-does-not-work-when-testing-on-arrow-fun/55422159#55422159). The following code should fix your problem.

```
 it('should SET the isDeleteUserModalOpen to true', () => {
    const deleteUserButton = wrapper.find('renderUsers').find('button');
    deleteUserButton.simulate('click');

    //this returns an object which will record interactions on 'openDeleteUserModal'
    const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'openDeleteUserModal');
    //Force update on the component is required for the spy to 'latch onto' an arrow function
    instance.forceUpdate();

    instance.openDeleteUserModal();

    //You have to check your spy object not the instance method
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

    expect(instance.state('isDeleteUserModalOpen')).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. But this is only part of the solution. My `OpenDeleteUserModal` is a method, (A function inside another function). So, it wasn't calling the second function, in order to check against the data, and the call..

Comment: @DimitrisEfst Check it now

Comment: I made a few more changes.

Comment: Looking at this a few years later. 
Thanks for your explanation.
But isn't it considered an anti pattern to use instance.state? From what I can see on the docs, they ask you to use the wrapper to access state values.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for solution, however, provided answers didn't work for me. After consulting the Enzyme doc, found that [setState()](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/setState.html) works fine for me. Below is my solution, with setState(), we don't need to call [Update()](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/update.html), as setState() re-render the component.

```
describe('OpenDeleteUserModal', () => {
  let wrapper: ReactWrapper;
  let instance: any;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Route render={props => <UsersOverviewScreen {...props} {...defaultProps} />} />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
    
  });
  it('should SET the isDeleteUserModalOpen to true', () => {
    expect(wrapper.setState({isDeleteUserModalOpen: true}).toBeTruthy();
  });
  it('should SET the userToDelete to mockUser', () => {
    expect(wrapper.setState({userToDelete: mockUser})).toEqual(mockUser);
  });
});
```